# Which operating systems support passing -j options to sub-makes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From the man page for gnu make:

> The ‘-j’ option is a special case (see Parallel Execution). If you set
>   it to some numeric value ‘N’ and your operating system supports it
>   (most any UNIX system will; others typically won’t), the parent make
>   and all the sub-makes will communicate to ensure that there are only
>   ‘N’ jobs running at the same time between them all. Note that any job
>   that is marked recursive (see Instead of Executing Recipes) doesn’t
>   count against the total jobs (otherwise we could get ‘N’ sub-makes
>   running and have no slots left over for any real work!)
>
> If your operating system doesn’t support the above communication, then
>   ‘-j 1’ is always put into MAKEFLAGS instead of the value you
>   specified. This is because if the ‘-j’ option were passed down to
>   sub-makes, you would get many more jobs running in parallel than you
>   asked for. If you give ‘-j’ with no numeric argument, meaning to run
>   as many jobs as possible in parallel, this is passed down, since
>   multiple infinities are no more than one.

Which common operating systems support or don't support this behavior?
And how can you tell if your os supports it?

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28994835/258523) covers this a bit.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I've edit the question to also ask how you can tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tell if your make supports this, run this command from your shell prompt:

```
echo 'all:;@echo $(filter jobserver,$(.FEATURES))' | make -f-
```

If it prints 'jobserver', then you have support.  If it prints nothing, you do not have support.  Or, if your OS doesn't support `echo` or pipelines, create a small makefile containing:

```
all:;@echo $(filter jobserver,$(.FEATURES))
```

then run `make` with that makefile.